# PC crashes when plugging in 2nd display

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently had to reinstall Windows on to my PC, which means that it automatically updated me to the latest version. Now when I try to plug in a second monitor, the whole PC freezes.

I have my main monitor plugged into the HDMI port on my GTX970 but when I try to plug the other HDMI into my motherboard, the whole PC freezes up and makes it impossible to do anything.

- The PC won't boot with the HDMI plugged in.
- If I unplug the HDMI from the graphics card, does the PC beep at me (Power On Self Test going off).
- Also, I can't access the bios without physically removing the graphics card from inside my PC.

Does anyone know a solution to fix all of these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Try different video drivers (older if you have the latest).

Try starting up the whole system with everything already connected.

If that does not work, try to disconnect the initial display and let only the HDMI one connected.

If that also does not work, your video card may have a bad HDMI port.

Comment: Starting with everything connected doesn't work, just gives me a black screen on monitor 1. Disconnecting the initial display causes it to beep at me. It's not the HDMI ports, as they work fine individually.

Comment: Switch cables to make sure both are good. If they are good, try using only the second HDMI port (the one causing the trouble).

Comment: Both cables are fine. Only using the second HDMI port causes the PC to beep at me, unless the video card is disconnected.

Comment: If you tried the already working monitor on the second port and it does the same, that means it's certainly a bad video card port.

Comment: No, it's definitely software. Before the reinstall, everything was working almost perfectly.

Comment: Software would not affect things at boot time.

Comment: But it wouldn't be the ports as the one on the mobo works fine if there is no video card installed into the PC. And the one on the graphics card works fine when it's inserted, but windows will crash if you insert the two together.

Comment: Yes, but the crash is actually caused by hardware. Now it's clear as you explained. You should check the UEFI BIOS Utility. Go to Graphics Configuration (usually under Advanced ).

There, try to set integrated GPU Multi-Monitor to [Enabled] and Primary Display to [Auto].

Comment: I can't access the BIOS with the graphics card installed, for some reason. So I have to remove the graphics card to access the bios.

Comment: This is one more clue that's something wrong with the BIOS settings.

Comment: Yeah, but how would I make it accept that a graphics card is plugged in if I can't access it with a graphics card plugged in? Oh, and the Mobo is an MSI Z68A-GD55 (G3)

Comment: I removed the GPU and went to the bios settings. IGD multi monitor was already enabled and I can't see a setting to change the default graphics adapter. Only the option for "intitiate graphic adapter" with "igd" or "peg"

Comment: IGD = Integrated Graphics Device, aka your iGPU on the CPU. It should be enabled for it to work. PEG = PCI Express Graphics, aka your 970.

Comment: Yes, but this setting controls what one is used at boot. Changing it to IGD doesn't work.

Comment: Booting with IGD should allow you access to BIOS even with the 970 connected. IGD should be both enabled and primary in BIOS if you want to use both cards.

Comment: I have changed it to IGD, and now the PC shows black screens when just plugged into the Mobo. (With the 970 plugged in too.)